# Turtlebot at IDF and Intel Joule

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I saw a turtlebot at IDF 2016 running an Intel Joule, and what appeared to be Ubuntu Core Snappy.  Does anyone know about this, or how to install Snappy on the Intel Joule?  It comes with a stripped down version of linux, which doesnt support Apt-Get or even a browser..... He said it was using ROS as well, so I assume if I can get Snappy on the Joule, I can install ROS.....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242362/turtlebot-at-idf-and-intel-joule/) by [wthierry](https://answers.ros.org/users/2695/wthierry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-08-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Definitely! Taken from [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/core):

> Ubuntu Core is a tiny, transactional version of Ubuntu for IoT devices and large container deployments. It runs a new breed of super-secure, remotely upgradeable Linux app packages known as snaps ‐ and it’s trusted by leading IoT players, from chipset vendors to device makers and system integrators.

Directions for installing it on the Joule are on the [same site](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/intel-joule/).

Indeed, Ubuntu Core is the same Ubuntu you know and love, but it's stripped down. As mentioned in the quote, it uses the **snap** packaging mechanism, which gets you automatic updates that are transactional (i.e. you can roll them back). Snaps bundle their dependencies, so a snap using ROS in most cases bundles the entire system into one snap. This is done using the snap build tool called [snapcraft](http://snapcraft.io/). There's a ROS example in the [snapcraft documentation](https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/blob/master/docs/ros-snap.md).

---

Originally posted by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) with karma: 347 on 2016-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1